# Why @Output doesn't emit anything (in angular 8)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to transfer an object to a pot component via @Output.

But emit doesn't return anything and when you put it in the log it's undefined.

This is my code:

Transmitter component :

```
@Output() menubuttonclicked = new EventEmitter<object>();
.
.
.
clickedmenu(id: string) {
    this.rclickemit.buttonid = id ;
    this.menubuttonclicked.emit(this.rclickemit);
  }
```

Transmitter html:

```
<button *ngFor ="let button of Setting.menu" (click)="clickedmenu(button.id)" mat-menu-item>
    <mat-icon>{{button.icon}}</mat-icon>
    <span>{{button.name}}</span>
  </button>
```

Recipient Component:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes['emit']) {
      console.log(this.emit);
    }
  }
```

But nothing can be printed on the console.
I gave the emit variable to get the output but no value in it.
Does anyone know the problem?

**Update**

Recipient Component:

```
<app-ir-graph-d3  [node]="nodes" [link]="links" [Setting]="Setting" (menubuttonclicked)="emit"></app-ir-graph-d3>
```

Comment: If you cannot log anything, it is probably because nothing triggers your `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook. Make sure you emit something properly first too.

Comment: Show html of parent or related part.
You must use `(menubuttonclicked)=parentFuction($event)` on the child html tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever in the Transmitting component you have used Recipient Component Please write eventEmmiter variable, and listen that event in the  Recipient Component.

```
<Recipient Component (menubuttonclicked) = "matButtonClicked($event)">
```

Recipient Component

```
matButtonClicked(event) {
 console.log(event) // 'this.rclickemit'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Output event emitter is used as an attribute with parentheses. For example:

In your recipient template:

```
<app-transmitter-component (menubuttonclicked)="onMenuButtonClicked($event)"></app-transmitter-component>
```

In your recipient component:

```
onMenuButtonClicked = (buttonID) => {
   console.log(buttonID)
}
```

For further reading: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

`ngOnChanges` is called when a change happend at data-bound properties such as `@Input` properties.

OnChange: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle of `Output`. Let me show an example:

yourOutputComponent.ts:

```
export class yourOutputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  onClick(){
    this.change.emit({newValue: 'I am your data' });
  }
}
```

and subscribed component `fooComponent.html`:

```
<yourOutput (change)="hello($event)"></yourOutput>
```

fooComponent.ts:

```
export class fooComponent implements OnInit {
    hello(event:any) {
        console.log(event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to the changes in the html of the Recipient Component not the `ngOnChanges`

```
<recipient-component (menubuttonclicked)='clickHandler($event)'></recipient-component>
```

Then in the typescript file, you declare teh `clickHandler` function and receive the input there.